# CSS Drop Shadow disabling link

Tags: html, css, image

I just followed a CSS tutorial on how to make a drop shadow effect on an image. It works really great except that my image is actually a link (in a menu). The problem is that when the dropshadow effect is activated, the link do not work anymore in IE8. It work great on Chrome but since it's an internal web application, people are only using IE8.

I'm sure there must be a property to add somewhere in my CSS code but I don't know...

Here is my CSS code:

```
.img-shadow {
  float:left;
  background: url(menupic/shadow.png) no-repeat bottom right;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
  }

.img-shadow img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: -6px 6px 6px -6px;
  padding: 4px;
  z-index: 10;
  }
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<a href="yyy.html"><span class='img-shadow' style='margin-left:3px;' ><img border=0 src="img.png" alt='menuitem' /></span></a>
```

Thanks!

P.S: Please, do not tell me that there is other way to achieve this effect. I know that :)

Comment: Can you link to the CSS tutorial that you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of puting the span into the anchor, I did the other way around and it work perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
<span class='img-shadow' style='margin-left:3px;' ><a href="yyy.htm"><img border=0 src="image.png" alt='menuitem' /></a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the overall HTML, CSS and the image you're using I'd say you're trying to place the image behind the anchor link? Right now with z-index: 10 you're telling it to be above normal elements and sitting on top of the anchor link and making it unusable.
Try:

```
z-index:-10;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, the z-indez:10 was not supposed to be on my post, it was for test purpose only. But your post put me in the right direction and I found the solution. I will post it as an answer as soon as I can.